# table not updating even the property is deleted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have EF in my project. I was trying to add FK (`ServiceID`) in the model and it was added but now im trying to remove it it doesn't change anything. I tried adding new property(`TestProp`) and then remove it and it works fine unlike the `ServiceID`. Why?

What I have done is:

1. Remove the property
2. Add-Migration mymigration
3. update-database

Comment: Why not remove the FK by hand?

Comment: @Marco what do you mean?

Comment: Go into the management suite for your RDBMS and drop it by hand: `ALTER TABLE FOO DROP CONSTRAINT ...`